# Is XSS possible in the value field of input tag?

Tags: reflected-xss

Let's say that I have a website with the following code in it:

`<input type="search" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="$query">`

With `$query` being the input reflected parameter here, I wish to launch an XSS but when I insert this payload `" onfocus="confirm(1)" autofocus="` nothing happens.

Instead, if I view the source page, the payload is interpreted as a string and the payload doesn't even break out of `value` attribute.

Is it possible to break out of the `value` attribute and launch an XSS or what type of technique should I learn to bypass this type of filter?

Comment: In principle this place can be used for XSS  - but only if the attacker provided value does not get properly escaped when inserted into this place and if no CSP blocks script execution. In your case it looks like that the value is not inserted in raw but somehow escaped or CSP blocks script execution, so that you cannot exploit it. It might still be possible to find a way if the escaping is not done properly - but this is unknown here. As for the trying and learning part - see the [various XSS cheat cheats](https://www.google.com/search?q=xss+cheat+sheet)

Answer (score 1):

If the application escapes double quotes within `$query`, there is no trivial way to break out of the attribute and perform an XSS attack.

In case you can trigger a mismatch between the character encoding assumed by the browser and the encoding used by the escape function, you can exploit the fact that the escape function may not be able to recognize (and then escape) double quotes:

```
<?php

// set the character set of the content to UTF-7
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-7');

// XSS vector; note that +ACI- is a double quote in UTF-7
$input = '+ACI- onclick=+ACI-alert(1) +ACI-';

// the escaping assumes UTF-8, leading to an encoding mismatch
$query = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="search" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="<?= $query ?>">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tested this in Chromium 114.0.5735.133. When you click on the field, you should see an alert.

[In ancient times, it was possible to make the browser use UTF-7 under certain circumstances](https://shiflett.org/blog/2005/googles-xss-vulnerability), so the attack was actually realistic. Recent browsers no longer have this vulnerability or reject UTF-7 altogether.